# How do curve modifiers rotate a mesh around for deformation?

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I have made a crude tree mesh and have created a bezier curve wrapped around the branch with the intention of animating a tapeworm like snake uncoiling from it. However, when applying the curve modifier the orientation of the faces is twisted quite radically and at a glance random due to the orientation of the points on the curve. I would prefer to have the top of the snake consistently pointing away from the tree branch.

Is there a way to accomplish this? While a less flat mesh would probably be simpler, a texture that was lighter for underbelly would probably have the same issue right? I tried rotating the curve's points but knew that doing so would make the curve itself not conform to the topology, and wish to learn a method of doing this where I sculpt, curve then deform a mesh to the curve as that sounds efficient and thought this would be a good test on how that workflow would work.

[image]